# Issue with PHP/MYSQLi Password validation using salt

Tags: php, hash, mysqli, salt

I am having an issue getting the password being stored on in mysql to match the Login password using salt.

Here is the code from my password creation:

```
        $hash = hash('sha256', $password);

        function createSalt()
        {
        $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            return substr($text, 0, 3);
        }

        $salt = createSalt();
        $password = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
```

Here is the code in my login page:

```
        $userData = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);

        $hash = hash('sha256', $password);

        $password = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . $hash);

        //$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) ); 

        if($password != $userData['Password']) // Incorrect password. So, redirect to login_form again.
```

There are no errors creating the password in mysql (the field is populated with i.e 0d02a88c1e1057a64df6b3fed4c6ad64e228313b803e9f9b36...

While the Login creates something like: 51839f9a15dac1f26825f4cd5d2ecf7ae83ea88d440415b04fb6ae41c3a0566f

Just not sure where the issue is. Thanks in advance, I am very new to PHP.

Comment: You can't be slapdash about this. Posting something 'like' your code generates isn't helpful. Your first step should be to verify by eye that the hashed password in your database matches your expected result. Then verify that each step through your process matches your expectations.

Comment: Aren't you always using different salt for password creation? That is one problem. The other that you might not put the `salt` information to `$userData`

Comment: @mike W what is slapdash? Obviously the example I gave are the EXACT ones in my mysql database and what is being created by the login page. But If I said these are my results, you would of put something condescending like "Well, every user can't have the same results" And I have traced it as much as I can based on my understanding of PHP. Thanks for your very unusful comments.

Comment: @Gabor Bakos - I thought the $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)); return substr($text, 0, 3); was creating a unique salt for each one and the $userData['Password'] was using the salt created in the creation page to make the match?

Comment: @86Tango Please read your own comments again: _While the Login creates __something like__ :_ Your other example is suffixed with ellipsis. Since you now say these are __exact__ presumably the ellipsis are present in your own code. I think 'slapdash' covers it nicely.

Comment: @Mike W Don't get your panties in a bunch. Again, your comments are not useful. Please go do your trolling elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have some confusing variable naming here - you use $password to represent both the plaintext password and the salt-and-hashed representation. That makes it harder to read your code.

Second, let's look at your code as a series of states to find where they might be going wrong:

1. Password entry. Is the same string being passed in both cases? Have you paid attention to whitespace and capitalization? Use a debugger to verify. If the plaintext password is not byte-for-byte identical, the initial sha256 hash should show differences at this point.
2. Salt generation/retrieval. Did you save/retrieve the exact same salt, byte-for-byte? Again, watch for whitespace/capitalization and also check that your database isn't silently truncating or changing the encoding for the string.
3. Compare the strings after they have been concatenated but before the second sha256 hash operation. By definition, since the final output is different, either your plaintext password or salt is not byte-for-byte identical. This will help you tell if one or both are the culprits.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at those things right now and respond back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and store your passwords more safe, with the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

The SHA-* algorithms are not appropriate for hashing passwords, because they are ways too fast. The function password_hash() will not only calculate a better suited BCrypt hash, it will also take care of the generation of a safe salt, and you won't have to store/retrieve the salt in a separate database field (it will become part of the resulting hash-value).

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```