# PHP login system does nothing at login

Tags: php, html, authentication, passwords

I can't figure it out why my login system does nothing at login. Can you help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <!--Audio player-->
      <audio autoplay loop>
          <source src="audio/audio9.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
          <source src="audio/audio9.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          Browserul tău nu suportă HTML5.
      </audio>   

      <?php
 require('config.php');
 session_start();
 // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
 if (isset($_POST['Username'])){
 $Username = $_POST['Username'];
 $Password = $_POST['Password'];
 $Username = stripslashes($Username);
 $Username = mysql_real_escape_string($Username);
 $Password = stripslashes($Password);
 $Password = mysql_real_escape_string($Password);
 //Checking is user existing in the database or not
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE Username='$Username' and Password='".sha1($Password)."'";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($rows==1){
 $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username;
 header("Location: profile.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
 }else{
         header("Location: ./eroare");
 }
 }else{
 }
?>

<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Vestige DayZ</title>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://vestigedayz.com/index.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.imgur.com/KHo2frf.png" />
<meta name="description" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow,all" />
<meta name="keywords" content="SA:MP Vestige Day Z" />
<meta name="author" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="img/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="img/manifest.json">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">


<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animsition.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/overlay.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <style>
      /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
.btn { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; padding: 4px 10px 4px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #333333; text-align: center;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); vertical-align: middle; background-color: #f5f5f5; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#e6e6e6, GradientType=0); border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6; border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); cursor: pointer; *margin-left: .3em; }
.btn:hover, .btn:active, .btn.active, .btn.disabled, .btn[disabled] { background-color: #e6e6e6; }
.btn-large { padding: 9px 14px; font-size: 15px; line-height: normal; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
.btn:hover { color: #333333; text-decoration: none; background-color: #e6e6e6; background-position: 0 -15px; -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; transition: background-position 0.1s linear; }
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover { text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); color: #ffffff; }
.btn-primary.active { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }
.btn-primary { background-color: #4a77d4; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#6eb6de), to(#4a77d4)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#6eb6de, endColorstr=#4a77d4, GradientType=0);  border: 1px solid #3762bc; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled] { filter: none; background-color: #4a77d4; }
.btn-block { width: 100%; display:block; }

* { -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -ms-box-sizing:border-box; -o-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box; }
html { width: 100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
body { 
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #092756;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%),-moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%, rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), linear-gradient(135deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3E1D6D', endColorstr='#092756',GradientType=1 );
}
.login { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.login h1 { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); letter-spacing:1px; text-align:center; }

input { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
}
input:focus { box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); }

    </style>


        <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="animsition-overlay">
  <div id="section-1">
    <header class="main_h">
      <div class="menufix"> <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-sample.png" alt="Hello"></a>
        <div class="mobile-toggle"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="out active animsition-link" href="index.html">ACASA</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="aboutproject.html">DESPRE PROIECT</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="gallery.html">GALERIE</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="forum">FORUM</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="UCP">UCP</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- / row --> 

    </header>
    <div class="hero">
      <h1 id="title-1">SA:MP DayZ<em><span>V</span>ESTIGE</em>Loghează-te la caracterul tău.</h1>


       <body>
    <div class="login">
    <form action'submit' method='POST'>     
        <input type="text" name="Username"'/> 
        <input type="password" name="Password"/>
        <input type='submit' name="submit" value='Loghează-te !' /> </form>             
    </form>
</div>


  <!-- END #section-1 -->

    <p class="dolje">&nbsp;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> &nbsp;www.vestigedayz.com- All rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- END #section-credits --> 
</div>
<!-- END .animsition-overla --> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/animsition.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.parallax-scroll.js"></script> 
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.cbpQTRotator.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#owl-partners").owlCarousel({

          autoPlay: 4000, 
          stopOnHover : true,
          pagination : false,
          items : 5,
          itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
          itemsDesktopSmall : [959,3]     
      });     
    });
</script> 
<script>
    $( function() {
    $( '#cbp-qtrotator' ).cbpQTRotator();                   
    });
</script> 
<script src="js/functions.js"></script> 
<script src="js/particle.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-15815880-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm looking throught code, it should send the logging person to his personal page, profile.php  but it does nothing.

I'm operating local host to learn about php & html. But I can't figure what doesn't allow users to log in.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Don't escape passwords before hashing them. That changes the password and might weaken them.

Comment: I'm guessing that the PHP and the form is in the same file? Where is the PHP located? Looking at the code, you must have it first, before _any_ output. Make sure there's no white spaces or anything before the opening PHP-tag. Also, check your servers error log for potential error messages.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm operationg on localhost. No server errors.  I've just updated with the all script so you can see it.

Comment: you dont have an `action` specified in `<form method='POST'>   `

Comment: @Lal oh just saw that, modified that but still won't enter in profile.php.   it just refreshes the page

Comment: turn on error reporting by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of the page and see if it displays any errors.

Comment: Your PHP code must be _first_ in your script since you're trying to modify headers and set sessions. You need to do that _before any_ output at all. Even if you're running it on localhost, you still have a web server installed and should look at it's error log.

Comment: `form action'submit' method='POST'>` is not correct..

Comment: If the form is going to post to the same page, you can actually omit the action-tag. It's not as intuitive when someone reads it, but it's valid.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Just moved PHP to above of the html.  Still doesn't happens anything. Just page refreshing.    where shall i place error_reporting(E_ALL) ?  inside of php tag?

Comment: You can read this post about showing all errors and warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in D:\xampp\htdocs\UCPBA\public_html\ucp\config.php on line 3
   singlest error

Comment: Please look at the third comment... You should rewrite your code to fit all the suggestions you've gotten in all th ecomments.

Comment: So i need to make a new php login system? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: You need to rewrite your code to use mysqli or PDO, yes. Then you should use Prepared Statements and use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` when hashing the passwords.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson im going to read tutorials. Thank you for assistance.

Comment: ***You shouldn't use [SHA1 password hashes](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1)***  or ***[MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422760/575765) could help to get you started with the login script.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should try to get used to is to start tags with lowercase letters instead of uppercase. So instead of using **name="Username"** use **name="username"** instead.
I would also recommend that you make a function that makes the password to the sha1 instead of doing .sha1($Password). Like this:

```
$pwd = sha1($Password);
```

And don't forget that you can get an error as you only have written one thing on mysqli_real_escape_string. It should be like this:

```
$Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($your_connection, $Password);
```

The same with username.

I would do it like this **:**

config.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "Your_server";
$dbuser = "Your_username_to_database";
$dbpass = "Your_password";
$dbname = "Your_database";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(!$conn){
die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'] { // The name of the button is submit.
$username = $_POST['username']; //Saving the values from the input username
$password = $_POST['password']; //Saving the values from the input password

$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']; //strips the tags
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']; //strips the tags

$username = stripslashes($username); //strips the slashes
$password = stripslashes($password); //strips the slashes

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);

$password = sha1($password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$pwd' LIMIT 1"; // Limit 1 to make that you can only login one user, not many at the same time.
$res = mysqli_query($your_connection, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$id = $row['id']; // Getting the id from the database
$db_password = $row['Password']: // getting the password from the database
if($Password == $db_password){ // Checking that the password is the same as from the database
   $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username; // Sets the session username to the username from the database
   $_SESSION['id'] = $id;  // Sets the session id to the id from the database
   header("Location: profile.php");
   } else {
   header("Location: ../eroare.php"); // Didn't know if it was an type or, but you need two dots to go up one directory, but if it is in the same folder. then it would just be erroare.php
   }
}
?>
```

As you can see so is the isset($_POST['submit']. It points to the button, not the form. But on the action you had submit. That is wrong. You need to point it towards a document. It can be the same document, or as I have done below. To another document (In this case: login.php).

And then use mysqli not mysql as it is decap

Then on index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <!--Audio player-->
      <audio autoplay loop>
          <source src="audio/audio9.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
          <source src="audio/audio9.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          Browserul tău nu suportă HTML5.
      </audio>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Vestige DayZ</title>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://vestigedayz.com/index.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.imgur.com/KHo2frf.png" />
<meta name="description" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow,all" />
<meta name="keywords" content="SA:MP Vestige Day Z" />
<meta name="author" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="img/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="img/manifest.json">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">


<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animsition.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/overlay.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<style>
/* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

* { 
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
  -ms-box-sizing:border-box; 
  -o-box-sizing:border-box; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline; 
  *zoom: 1;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px; 
  color: #333333; 
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  background-color: #f5f5f5; 
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); 
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); 
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); 
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); 
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); 
  background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#e6e6e6, GradientType=0); 
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6; 
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); 
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); 
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); 
  cursor: pointer; 
  *margin-left: .3em;
}

.btn:hover, .btn:active, .btn.active, .btn.disabled, .btn[disabled] {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.btn-large {
  padding: 9px 14px; 
  font-size: 15px; 
  line-height: normal; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none; 
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-position: 0 -15px; 
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; 
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; 
  -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; 
  -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; 
  transition: background-position 0.1s linear; 
}

.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 
  color: #ffffff; 
}

.btn-primary.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

  .btn-primary {
  background-color: #4a77d4; 
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); 
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); 
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#6eb6de), to(#4a77d4)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); 
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); 
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); 
  background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#6eb6de, endColorstr=#4a77d4, GradientType=0);
  border: 1px solid #3762bc; 
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled] {
  filter: none;
  background-color: #4a77d4;
}

.btn-block {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
}

html { 
  width: 100%; 
  height:100%; 
  overflow:hidden; 
}

body { 
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #092756;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%),-moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%, rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), linear-gradient(135deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3E1D6D', endColorstr='#092756',GradientType=1 );
}

.login { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}

.login h1 { 
  color: #fff; 
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
  letter-spacing:1px; 
  text-align:center; 
}

input { 
  width: 100%; 
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
  -o-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
  transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
}

input:focus { 
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
}
</style>
<script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="animsition-overlay">
  <div id="section-1">
    <header class="main_h">
      <div class="menufix"> <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-sample.png" alt="Hello"></a>
        <div class="mobile-toggle"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="out active animsition-link" href="index.html">ACASA</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="aboutproject.html">DESPRE PROIECT</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="gallery.html">GALERIE</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="forum">FORUM</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="UCP">UCP</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- / row --> 

    </header>
    <div class="hero">
      <h1 id="title-1">SA:MP DayZ<em><span>V</span>ESTIGE</em>Loghează-te la caracterul tău.</h1>


       <body>
    <div class="login">
    <form action="login.inc.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="username">
       <input type="password" name="password">
       <button type="submit" name="login">Loghează-te !</button>
    </form>
</div>


  <!-- END #section-1 -->

    <p class="dolje">&nbsp;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> &nbsp;www.vestigedayz.com- All rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- END #section-credits --> 
</div>
<!-- END .animsition-overla --> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/animsition.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.parallax-scroll.js"></script> 
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.cbpQTRotator.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#owl-partners").owlCarousel({

          autoPlay: 4000, 
          stopOnHover : true,
          pagination : false,
          items : 5,
          itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
          itemsDesktopSmall : [959,3]     
      });     
    });
</script> 
<script>
    $( function() {
    $( '#cbp-qtrotator' ).cbpQTRotator();                   
    });
</script> 
<script src="js/functions.js"></script> 
<script src="js/particle.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-15815880-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You ignored all those bold warnings in the comments. The SHA-* is not appropriate to hash passwords, because it is way too fast. If you do it correctly with a password-hash function (BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2, Argon2) then you cannot search for the password in the SQL query, because the hashes are salted.