# Error while creating password with md5 in php

Tags: php, mysqli, passwords, password-encryption

I have created an admin table and login panel for admin in my website. i inserted the data into admin table like

`insert into admin values('admin',md5('admin123'))`

the values got added and the password was added in the encrypted format.

But when i try to login to my admin panel its showing

> incorrect password

what could be the issue?

Comment: You made it wrong.

Comment: how can i do it

Comment: MD5 is not encryption.

Comment: can you tell me how to add password into the table in encryption format

Comment: Don't use MD5 for passwords. If you're using PHP, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: Why do you have both `mysql` and `oracle` tags? Which database are you really using?

Comment: can anyone tell me how to insert password using password_hash()

Comment: In another answer I wrote some [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422760/575765) of how passwords can be stored with password_hash(). One cannot use the database query alone, instead the programing environment is used to calculate the password hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change links below for using php hash methods;

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

with using

```
string password_hash ( string $password , int $algo [, array $options ] )
```

method u can hash your password, and pass it to your database with hashed. There are different kinds of hash methods changed by your parameters like PASSWORD_DEFAULT, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, PASSWORD_ARGON2I

Then you can use

```
bool password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )
```

method for verify your password which came from form with your hash that include your database

Comment: can you tell me the complete query

Answer (score -2):

```
 $new=md5('admin123');
 $query=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into admin values('admin','$new')");
```

Try this code

Comment: Don't use MD5, use `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: as the question ask , i just give the posible answer sorry for not suggesting

Comment: @DrianDrian Do not help people jump off bridges and this is worse since it puts the users at risk.