# php decrypt password does not work

Tags: php, hash, passwords, verification, php-password-hash

encrypt the password in the database with the following code:

```
$pas = $_POST['password'];    
$pass = password_hash($pas, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

in the solucioncontroller.php I try to verify the encrypted password but it does not work

```
class solucionController {
include_once 'model/solucion.php';

public function Login()
{
    $solucion = new solucion();
    if (isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $login = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
        $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
        $solucion = $this->model->Logeo($login, $password);
        $pass= $this->model->getpass();
        if (password_verify($password, $pass)&&$solucion == 1)
        {
            setcookie('usuario', $login, time() + 3600);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["Usuario"] = $login;
            header("Location: view/header.php");
            header("Location: view/solucion/solucion.php");
            header("Location: view/Footer.php");
        }
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}
}
```

in the model solucion.php I search for the user and the password entered in the login view

```
class solucion {
public $res;

public function Logeo($login, $pass)
{
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM logeo WHERE usuario = :login AND pass = :password";
        $resultado = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
        $resultado->bindValue(":password", $pass);
        $resultado->execute();
        $numero_registro = $resultado->rowCount();
        if ($numero_registro != 0)
        {  
            return 1;
        }
       $this->res = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
}

public function getpass(){
    return $this->res['pass'];
}
```

in the login view is the form where you enter the username and password

```
<?php 
if(isset($_COOKIE['usuario'])){
require 'view/solucion/solucion.php';
}
else{


?>
<a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="?c=solucion&a=Invitado">Invitado</a>
<h1>Introduce tus datos</h1>
    <form action="?c=solucion&a=Login" method="post">
        <div class="container">
        <label for="login"><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese usuario" name="login" required>
<label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese Contraseña" name="password" required>
<button type="submit">Login</button>             
            </div>
        </form>
<?php }?>
```

when entering the username and password, the data is deleted and I remain in the login view

Comment: You should fetch data using `usuario` only not using `usuario` and `pass` from database. Because password saved in database is hashed and can't be compared with simple text password entered by user.

Comment: First you should not escape the password before hashing and then one cannot search for a hashed password with a query because they are salted. I tried to explain the correct steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422760/575765).

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch data using `usuario` only not using `usuario` and `pass` from database. Because password saved in database is hashed and can't be compared with simple text password entered by user. Change the model code as below:

```
class solucion {

    public $res;

    public function Logeo($login, $pass) {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM logeo WHERE usuario = :login";
            $resultado = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
            $resultado->execute();
            $numero_registro = $resultado->rowCount();
            if ($numero_registro != 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            $this->res = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public function getpass() {
    return $this->res['pass'];
}
```

Also need to get password from request as:

```
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

instead of

```
$password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
```

Comment: After making the change, decryption still does not work