# Can I decrypt a password with c#, that was encrypted with PASSWORD_BCRYPT in php?

Tags: c#, php, hash, bcrypt

I am not sure if I can decrypt passwords with c#, that i stored in a mysql database. I encrypted these passwords in php using PASSWORD_BCRYPT.
And if it is possible how can I do it? Sorry but i'm a beginner and I didn't find any help on the internet. This is the piece of code I used to encrypt my passwords.

```
$passwort = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['passwort']);
$hash = password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

After reading the comments I tried doing so in c# but it always says wrong password

```
string email = textBox1.Text;
        string password = textBox2.Text;
        string passwordHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password);
        MessageBox.Show(passwordHash);
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=CIAO6CIAO6;database=kontoprogramm");
        int i = 0;
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select KLPPassword from tklassenlehrpersonen where KLPEmail = '" + email + "' and KLPPassword = '" + passwordHash + "'", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
        if (i == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Falsche Email oder Kennwort!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Angemeldet!");
        }
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: You typically don't decrypt passwords. If you want to see if a password is correct you'd encrypt the password you're checking and if the encrypted password matches the stored encrypted password then it's good.

Comment: ah thank you. And then is it possible to encrypt the password in c# with the same hash algorithm of the PASSWORD_BCRYPT function of php, so I can compare them?

Comment: BCRYPT is not an encryption method, it is a [hashing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification), thus there is no way to *decrypt* it.

Comment: The call to the method `real_escape_string` is incorrect. If you were trying to use it to prevent SQL injection then you should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @Dharman Ok thanks. Also how can I compare the hash string that I have in the database, created with the BCRYPT function in php, with the password that the user enters in my c# programm?

Comment: https://cmatskas.com/a-simple-net-password-hashing-implementation-using-bcrypt/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot decrypt, only if you effort to troubleshooting and hack the password decryption, for example, using [Brute Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) technique etc, because finally result from PHP by password_hash function is generates a hashed password, hash result. By the hash primary concept, cannot be reversible, but been comparable.

You may compare password hashs using PHP function [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) (comparing stored hash from database with the inputed password from your C# Application). If your requirement is really decrypt, it's need to change the focus of your post, re-think to troubleshooting and hack the password decryption, for example, using [Brute Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) technique etc.

Now, let's go to solution: you have two ways:

a) Create an PHP WebService parameterized with the "Clear Text" as input parameter, and get the output result as a encrypted text password; the core of Web Service (in PHP) uses the password_hash with PASSWORD_BCRYPT option, to encrypt. After, your C# code consumes the encrypted data and compare this output hash with stored hash from Database; however, this alternative needs to invest many efforts in security at WebServer and WebService layers. For example, your C# code consuming this PHP Web Service as code bellow:

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webclient_DownloadStringCompleted);
webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://ws.phpurl.com/?password=stackoverflow@12345"));

void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string phpWsEncryptedPass = e.Result;
    string databaseEncryptedPass = //TO DO: query Database
                                   //using WHERE statement,
                                   //parsing 'phpWsEncryptedPass' as parameter;
}
```

b) **OR**, download the [binaries](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/exif.installation.php) of the respective PHP version for Windows that you work'on, understand these DLLs methods using a DLL Reflector application (for example [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/)) and use [C# Interop features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices) to import the DLL thta have the [password_hash](https://php.net/password_hash) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to consume this in your C# code; you need to make efforts to open the DLL, to get the correctly methods declaration. Note: this way is suggest because the Core of PHP writted in C/C++ and a C# code can be consume the DLL of PHP for Windows binaries, this code bellow has an example to do this:

```
    [DllImport(@"C:\ProgramFiles\PHP\php_mbstring.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern IntPtr password_hash(string clearTextpassword, int option)

    [DllImport(@"C:\ProgramFiles\PHP\php_mbstring.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool password_verify(string clearTextpassword, string hash)
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search for a hash in the database, because of the salt, instead search by username only and take the stored hash for verification. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422760/575765) shows how to do it in PHP, though the principle is the same.

And don't escape the user input before calling `password_hash()` this calls for trouble.